# oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setLongInternal throws invalid column index

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, quarkus

From Quarkus2.6.2/Hibernate5.6.1 to our current Quarkus2.8.2/Hibernate5.6.8 we are getting an invalid column index error when updating one of our entities.
The identical code did work without any problems under Quarkus1.13.7/Hibernate5.4.29.
We are using

```
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=oracle
quarkus.hibernate-orm.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9iDialect
```

My question is, whether this is a problem of:

1. The Oracle driver?
2. Hibernate?
3. Quarkus?
4. Something wrong in our code?

Here is the entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_PREFERENCES")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@SequenceGenerator(name = "user_preferences_id_sequence", sequenceName = "USER_PREFERENCES_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
public class Preferences {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "user_preferences_id_sequence")
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "TYP")
    private String typ;

    @Column(name = "MODEX")
    private String modex;

    @Column(name = "JSON")
    private String json;
}
```

And here is the DB-Table as created via Liquibase:

```
<createTable tableName="USER_PREFERENCES">
    <column name="ID" type="NUMBER(38,0)">
        <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true" />
    </column>
    <column name="MODEX" type="VARCHAR2(12)"/>
    <column name="TYP" type="VARCHAR2(100)"/>
    <column name="JSON" type="CLOB"/>
</createTable>

leading to:

ID  NUMBER(38,0)
MODEX   VARCHAR2(12 CHAR)
TYP VARCHAR2(100 CHAR)
JSON    CLOB
```

Upon calling `em.persist(preferences)` Hibernate creates the following output in both, the working and the not-working versions:

```
2022-05-16 08:50:39,914 DEBUG [org.hib.SQL] (executor-thread-1)
    update
        USER_PREFERENCES
    set
        JSON=?,
        MODEX=?,
        TYP=?
    where
        ID=?
Hibernate:
    update
        USER_PREFERENCES
    set
        JSON=?,
        MODEX=?,
        TYP=?
    where
        ID=?
2022-05-16 08:50:39,918 TRACE [org.hib.typ.des.sql.BasicBinder] (executor-thread-1) binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [{"autoSearch":true,"filter":{"statusId":2,"userId":55,"testProp":"xxx"}}]
2022-05-16 08:50:39,919 TRACE [org.hib.typ.des.sql.BasicBinder] (executor-thread-1) binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [testB985B]
2022-05-16 08:50:39,921 TRACE [org.hib.typ.des.sql.BasicBinder] (executor-thread-1) binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [search_prefs]
2022-05-16 08:50:39,923 TRACE [org.hib.typ.des.sql.BasicBinder] (executor-thread-1) binding parameter [4] as [BIGINT] - [11]
```

In the not-working version, this leads to

```
2022-05-16 09:06:51,292 DEBUG [org.hib.eng.jdb.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (executor-thread-0) could not update: [de.my.app.preferences.entity.Preferences#11] [update USER_PREFERENCES set JSON=?, MODEX=?, TYP=? where ID=?]: java.sql.SQLException: Ung³ltiger Spaltenindex
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setLongInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:5005)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setLong(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4996)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.setLong(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:207)
        at io.agroal.pool.wrapper.PreparedStatementWrapper.setLong(PreparedStatementWrapper.java:148)
        at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BigIntTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(BigIntTypeDescriptor.java:46)
        at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:73)
        at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:276)
        at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:271)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrateId(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3121)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3093)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3527)
        ... 139 more
```

Comment: Do you just need to add an `@Lob` annotation to the entity on the `JSON` column?

Comment: @MT0 I tried with `@Lob` annotation, but without any change unfortunately

Comment: I also tried with `Integer id` instead of `Long id`, consequently leading to `OraclePreparedStatement.setIntegerInternal` throwing the error

Comment: Can you compare the oracle jdbc driver used in your case?  which version can work? Are those 2 scenaios using the same version of oracle jdbc driver?

Comment: @SeanH the last working version used com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc8:jar:21.1.0.0:compile   -> non working versions use com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc11:jar:21.3.0.0:compile to com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc11:jar:21.5.0.0:compile

Comment: @SeanH I just wanted to try with new Quarkus-version plus old (working) jdbc-driver, but this unfortunalety leads to io.quarkus.jdbc.oracle.deployment.OracleProcessor#configureAgroalConnection threw an exception: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: AGROAL   so it's not really compatible

Comment: From your description,  perhaps you can fire a BUG to Quarkus system directly.  Seems it's easy to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Already did as @SeanH advised: [here is the link to the issue](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/25593)

Answer (score 0):

Escaping the column name with backtick character will solve the issue.

```
@Column(name = "`JSON`")
private String json;
```